# Python: Creating a new list that is dependent on the content of another list

Tags: python, list, append, nested-loops

I am passing a function a list populated with strings. I want this function to take each of those strings and iterate through them, executing two different actions depending on the letters found in each string, then displaying them as the separate and now changed strings in a new list.

Specifically, when the program iterates through each string and finds a consonant, it should write that consonant in the order that it was found, into the new list. If the program finds a vowel in the current string, it should append 'xy' before the vowel, then the vowel itself.

As an example:

If the user input: "how now brown cow", the output of the function should be: "hxyow nxyow brxyown cxyow". I've tried nested for loops, nested while loops, and variations between. What's the best way to accomplish this? Cheers!

Comment: what you have tried show us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> def xy(st):
...     my_list,st1 =[],''
...     for x in st:
...         if x in 'aeiou':
...             st1 += 'xy'+x
...         elif x in 'cbdgfhkjmlnqpsrtwvyxz':
...             my_list.append(x)
...             st1 += x
...     return my_list,st1    
... 
>>> my_string="how now brown cow"
>>> xy(my_string)
(['h', 'w', 'n', 'w', 'b', 'r', 'w', 'n', 'c', 'w'], 'hxyow nxyow brxyown cxyow')
```

In above function for iterates through string when it find vowel concatenate xy+vowel else it append consonant to list, at last returns list and string

Comment: Thank you! This was very close to how I had it at one point, but you bridged the gap for me!

Answer (score 1):

For every character in old string check if it is vowel or consonant and create new string accordingly.

```
old = "how now brown cow"
new = ""
for character in old:
    if character in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        new = new + "xy" + character
    else:
        new = new + character
print(new)
```

I gave you the idea and now I leave it as exercise to make it work for list of strings. Also make appropriate changes if you are using `python2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I tried fiddling around with it and eventually got it to work :) I would upvote but I do not have enough 'reputation'

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this using a list comprehension:

```
old_str = "how now brown cow"
new_str = ''.join(["xy" + c if c in "aeiou" else c for c in old_str])
print new_str
```

But if you're processing a lot of data it'd be more efficient to use a set of vowels, eg

```
vowels = set("aeiou")
old_str = "how now brown cow"
new_str = ''.join(["xy" + c if c in vowels else c for c in old_str])
print new_str
```

Note that these programs simply copy all characters that aren't vowels, i.e., spaces, numbers and punctuation get treated as if they were consonants.